# Solving equation for specified parameters

Tags: inequalities, function-comparison, parameters

I have a long expression which depends of several parameters

```
Expression=1 - (2 x (m + \[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/(1 + 2 \[Alpha]) + 
1/(2 (-3 - 5 m - \[Alpha] - m \[Alpha] - \[Alpha]^2)) (6 + 10 m - 
144 x - 144 m x + 12 m x^2 + 24 m^2 x^2 + 12 m^3 x^2 + 
24 \[Alpha] + 24 m \[Alpha] - 24 x \[Alpha] - 24 m x \[Alpha] + 
24 \[Alpha]^2 - 12 x \[Beta] - 12 m x \[Beta] + 24 x^2 \[Beta] + 
24 m x^2 \[Beta] - 24 x \[Alpha] \[Beta] +...
```

and I want to check whether that expression is positive for [Alpha], [Beta] > 0 and m a natural number.
How can I specify the conditions for [Alpha], [Beta] and m, and the interval for my x (which is [0,1]) and evaluate the truth value of 'Expression > 0'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you did not give complete code to try. But you could see if `Reduce` will do it

```
expr = 1 - (2 x (m + α + β))/(1 + 2 α) + 
  1/(2 (-3 - 5 m - α - m α - α^2)) (6 + 10 m - 
     144 x - 144 m x + 12 m x^2 + 24 m^2 x^2 + 12 m^3 x^2 + 
     24 α + 24 m α - 24 x α - 24 m x α + 
     24 α^2 - 12 x β - 12 m x β + 24 x^2 β + 
     24 m x^2 β - 24 x α β)

Reduce[expr > 0 && α > 0 && β > 0 && 0 < x < 1 && 
  Element[m, Integers] && m > 0, x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]